# Activity A is not Coming From Activity B

Tags: android, fragment, onresume

I am starting B Fragment from Fragment A.Now from Fragment B i hit Home Button.Again i open the app and it calls OnResume. Now if i hit back button it exit from the app.What should i do?

Fragment A to Fragment B Activity

```
   Intent find = new Intent(getActivity(),FindActivityMain.class);
                    find.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                    ***startActivity(find);***Here i am not finishing the activity.
```

Fragment B Activity to Fragment B transaction code

```
    Fragment myfindfragment = new   FindFragmentMain(FindActivityMain.this,mylistitem,FindActivityMain.this,distance,featuredAD);



        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.blankfindlandingframe, myfindfragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();         


}
```

Fragment A Activity is "SingleInstance" declared in Manifest.In General the Back Navigation works Perfect.But If i do these step ->
1.) Click Home Button
2.) Again long press home button to restore the app
3.) Click back button.Exit from the app.

This 3rd Step should not occur.

Please Help !!

Comment: Both the fragmen/ts are in different activity or you are loading them in same activity

Comment: Why do you have the Activity SingleInstance? Be careful with it. Now your question, do you intend to go back to `Fragment` A on pressing back button?

Comment: @AshwinNBhanushali both fragment are under separate activities..Activity A has Fragment A like this

Comment: @FunLove could you please tell what exactly you want to do?

Comment: @Sufian Yes Sufian...In the general its going back to Fragment A from Fragment B.But hitting Home Button and again i open the app and it calls OnResume. Now if i hit back button it exit from the app

Comment: @Sufian Back Navigation working perfectly in general.The problem appears if i hit home button and and long pressing the home button and openning the app again.That time if i hit back button it exit from the app.Not going to Fragment A.

Comment: Since your activity A is single instance it will be kept on different task hence relaunching and back press exists the app.Please have a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html.

Comment: @AshwinNBhanushali So WHat should i do??? If i remove Single instance then it will be some problem.keeping both of my requirement is not possible ?

Answer (score 0):

remove find.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: It does not help either

Answer (score 0):

add your code 'addToBackStack(null)'

```
Fragment myfindfragment = new   FindFragmentMain(FindActivityMain.this,mylistitem,FindActivityMain.this,distance,featuredAD);



        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.blankfindlandingframe, myfindfragment).addToBackStack(null).commitAllowingStateLoss();         


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside Activity B add this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  
{
     if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0)
     {
        finish();
        return false;
     }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: it's irrelevant, it just prevents back button to work, 
and you can call finish() inside if condition before return.